# Trying to program a simple game, ideas for mouse control and random element

Tags: python, random

I am writing a game in *Python* that presents the user with a number of squares, where one is the winning square. However, I'm stuck for how to make the squares respond to a click and how to hide the winning square in a different location each time. Here is my code so far:

```
# Import library
import pygame
# Initialise game engine
pygame.init()
# Examples
black = (0, 0, 0)
white = (255, 255, 255)
green = (0, 255, 0)
red = (255, 0, 0)
blue = (0, 0, 255)
# Screen dimensions
size=[700,500]
screen=pygame.display.set_mode(size)

pygame.display.set_caption("Lewis Tough - Find The Gold")
pi=3.141592653
done=False
clock=pygame.time.Clock()
font=pygame.font.Font("C:/Windows/Fonts/TCM_____.ttf", 50)
while done==False:
for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
        done=True
#all evt processing above here

#start of game logic
#end of game logic

#start of drawing
screen.fill(white)
pygame.draw.rect(screen,green,[20,20,50,50],2)
pygame.draw.rect(screen,green,[70,70,50,50],2)
pygame.draw.rect(screen,green,[20,70,50,50],2)
pygame.draw.rect(screen,green,[70,20,50,50],2)
pygame.draw.rect(screen,green,[120,20,50,50],2)
pygame.draw.rect(screen,green,[170,70,50,50],2)
pygame.draw.rect(screen,green,[120,70,50,50],2)
pygame.draw.rect(screen,green,[170,20,50,50],2)
#breakafter8
pygame.draw.rect(screen,green,[120,120,50,50],2)
pygame.draw.rect(screen,green,[170,170,50,50],2)
pygame.draw.rect(screen,green,[120,170,50,50],2)
pygame.draw.rect(screen,green,[170,120,50,50],2)
pygame.draw.rect(screen,green,[20,120,50,50],2)
pygame.draw.rect(screen,green,[70,170,50,50],2)
pygame.draw.rect(screen,green,[20,170,50,50],2)
pygame.draw.rect(screen,green,[70,120,50,50],2)
#sec3
pygame.draw.rect(screen,green,[220,20,50,50],2)
pygame.draw.rect(screen,green,[270,70,50,50],2)
pygame.draw.rect(screen,green,[220,70,50,50],2)
pygame.draw.rect(screen,green,[270,20,50,50],2)
pygame.draw.rect(screen,green,[320,20,50,50],2)
pygame.draw.rect(screen,green,[370,70,50,50],2)
pygame.draw.rect(screen,green,[320,70,50,50],2)
pygame.draw.rect(screen,green,[370,20,50,50],2)
#sec4
pygame.draw.rect(screen,green,[320,120,50,50],2)
pygame.draw.rect(screen,green,[370,170,50,50],2)
pygame.draw.rect(screen,green,[320,170,50,50],2)
pygame.draw.rect(screen,green,[370,120,50,50],2)
pygame.draw.rect(screen,green,[220,120,50,50],2)
pygame.draw.rect(screen,green,[270,170,50,50],2)
pygame.draw.rect(screen,green,[220,170,50,50],2)
pygame.draw.rect(screen,green,[270,120,50,50],2)
#next half
pygame.draw.rect(screen,green,[20,220,50,50],2)
pygame.draw.rect(screen,green,[70,270,50,50],2)
pygame.draw.rect(screen,green,[20,270,50,50],2)
pygame.draw.rect(screen,green,[70,220,50,50],2)
pygame.draw.rect(screen,green,[120,220,50,50],2)
pygame.draw.rect(screen,green,[170,270,50,50],2)
pygame.draw.rect(screen,green,[120,270,50,50],2)
pygame.draw.rect(screen,green,[170,220,50,50],2)
#breakafter8
pygame.draw.rect(screen,green,[120,320,50,50],2)
pygame.draw.rect(screen,green,[170,370,50,50],2)
pygame.draw.rect(screen,green,[120,370,50,50],2)
pygame.draw.rect(screen,green,[170,320,50,50],2)
pygame.draw.rect(screen,green,[20,320,50,50],2)
pygame.draw.rect(screen,green,[70,370,50,50],2)
pygame.draw.rect(screen,green,[20,370,50,50],2)
pygame.draw.rect(screen,green,[70,320,50,50],2)
#sec3
pygame.draw.rect(screen,green,[220,220,50,50],2)
pygame.draw.rect(screen,green,[270,270,50,50],2)
pygame.draw.rect(screen,green,[220,270,50,50],2)
pygame.draw.rect(screen,green,[270,220,50,50],2)
pygame.draw.rect(screen,green,[320,220,50,50],2)
pygame.draw.rect(screen,green,[370,270,50,50],2)
pygame.draw.rect(screen,green,[320,270,50,50],2)
pygame.draw.rect(screen,green,[370,220,50,50],2)
#sec4
pygame.draw.rect(screen,green,[320,320,50,50],2)
pygame.draw.rect(screen,green,[370,370,50,50],2)
pygame.draw.rect(screen,green,[320,370,50,50],2)
pygame.draw.rect(screen,green,[370,320,50,50],2)
pygame.draw.rect(screen,green,[220,320,50,50],2)
pygame.draw.rect(screen,green,[270,370,50,50],2)
pygame.draw.rect(screen,green,[220,370,50,50],2)
pygame.draw.rect(screen,green,[270,320,50,50],2)
#start of text

text=font.render("Welcome to Find the Gold!", True, black)
screen.blit(text, [100,425])

score = 0
texta = font.render("Score:"+str(score), True, black)
screen.blit(texta,[480,50])



pygame.display.flip()


#end of drawing


clock.tick(20)

pygame.quit()
```

Does anyone have any ideas?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: first of all...you probably want to make a loop to help you draw thos tiles so the code will be much more readable.

Answer (score 0):

I would highly recommend several things.

1. Read [making games with python & pygame.](http://inventwithpython.com/pygame/) It goes over what a typical python/pygame game should like and explains useful things that you would need for this question. (Things like event.coords, event.type == MOUSEDOWN, having a list of coords, pygame.Rect objects, etc.) Plus it's free and open source!
2. Open up your interactive shell and type "import this". Seriously, readability does count. And your code is not readable. Then, read [PEP-8](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) and make your code readable.
3. Those 65 lines of pygame.draw.rect() can be replaced with less than 10 lines of a well written for loop.
4. Instead of telling your computer to draw a rect over and over, specify where the rects are with a data-type. Specifically, have a list of pygame.Rect objects. These can be written in one by one, (not recommended) or you could generate them with something like this:

   ```
   for row in range(number_of_rows):
       for column in range(number_of_columns):
           width = 50
           height = 50
           x = column * width + 20
           y = column * height + 20
           all_rects.append(pygame.Rect(x, y, width, height))
   ```

   (Definitely recommended)
5. Look into objects and classes. [This](http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/python/threads/290971/classes-in-python-...-a-short-tutorial) looks like a decent tutorial explaining it.